# How find a variable value in MOD expression?

Tags: math, modulo, shift

9 = 2^X mod 11

What is X and how do you find X?

Its related to finding the plain text in RSA algorithm and I'm writing a C program for it.

Comment: belongs on mathoverflow?

Comment: Its related to finding the plain text in RSA algorithm and I'm writing a C program for it, that's why I asked in stack overflow. :)

Comment: chiaotzu: That's OK then. I thought about that, actually. That's what the question mark in my comment meant. I suggest you clarify your question to include your intention too. It makes the question easier to find for future readers.

Comment: My gut feeling is that there would be several solutions to this problem. A C program (as chiaotzu suggested) could find a *numerical* solution.

Comment: I'm the one who asked the question LOL. I have to do it in C program. But I don't know how. Also how do it using simple math and how do shift mod to left so that I can solve it. We can shift * and / to left, but I have no idea how to shift mod :(

Comment: Is this article of any help?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I guess its too much hard to do it. Thanks a lot anyways, I suck at maths and can't get whatever typed in wiki. Ain't there any simple solution to shift it like multiplication and division?
like
if 3*X=6 then we write it as X = 6/3 and find X. 

Any solution like that? :\

Comment: "belongs on mathoverflow" : no way! You post something like this and it will get closed before you can say "Abelian group" -- mathoverflow is for mathematician discussion for people who are already very familiar with mathematical topics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is 6 + 10i for any integer i.

A simple way to get solutions for small moduli is to iterate over all values of x. You only need to check between 0 and 10 (= 11 - 1) to find the first solution, if any solution exists.

```
x = 0
while x < 50:
    if 9 == 2**x % 11:
         print x
    x += 1
```

Output:

```
6
16
26
36
46
```

Obviously this will take a long time if the modulus is large.

More information is on the [Discrete Logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) page. Note:

> No efficient classical algorithm for
>   computing general discrete logarithms
>   logbg is known. The naive algorithm is
>   to raise b to higher and higher powers
>   k until the desired g is found; this
>   is sometimes called trial
>   multiplication. This algorithm
>   requires running time linear in the
>   size of the group G and thus
>   exponential in the number of digits in
>   the size of the group.

If it were easy to invert modular exponetiation, it wouldn't be a good cryptographic primitive.

Comment: For this kind of arithmetic it is __much__ better to compute the powers by multiplying and doing the modulus at each step. This way the numbers stay small (always smaller than the modulus). This makes it possible to do the modular exponentation for very large exponents, which is exactly the case in cryptographic algorithms.

Comment: Yes, this is in fact exactly what the Wikipedia page suggests, under the name 'trial multiplication'. However it is still very slow. It is much better to use something like Baby Step, "Giant Step". You can read about it on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, sequence of 2^n mod 11 will be cyclical.

2^0 mod 11 = 1
2^1 mod 11 = 2
2^2 mod 11 = 4
2^3 mod 11 = 8
2^4 mod 11 = 5
2^5 mod 11 = 10
**2^6 mod 11 = 9**
2^7 mod 11 = 7
2^8 mod 11 = 3
2^9 mod 11 = 6
2^10 mod 11 = 1  
2^11 mod 11 = 2

So, cycle length is 10.

2^n mod 11 = 9 for n=6+10*m where m is integer

Comment: I don't get this way...

n=6+10*m

how you found 6 and 10 from nowhere? :\

Comment: from nowhere? "6": see the answer, 2^6 is a particular solution of the equation. "10": again, see the answer, the cycle repeats every 10 powers of 2.

Comment: But you have to find the 6 first using bruteforce, so what's the use of that n=6+10*m if we got the value already. Sorry if I'm being an idiot. :\

Answer (score 0):

I think that can be solved using [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). Another way is calculating 9=2^X in F<sub>11</sub> (Z/11Z), but that's part of modular arithmetic, too.

Another solution (where you'll find only ONE solution) is to solve the equation numerically, that's probably easier in a C program.